# Excel connection string for Excel created on Mac

Tags: excel, connection-string

I've been looking everywhere for the answer to this question. I have a working application that imports Excel files using Microsoft.Jet.OleDB.

Now it seems that when a user on a Mac uploads an Excel file, all special characters (ë, é, ç, ...) are replaced by other characters after the import. This has something to do with character encoding but I haven't discovered in what format the Excel seems to be stored when saved on a Mac.

Right now, I have this connectionstring:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;""
```

I've tried adding a CharacterSet to my connection string, but it's always the same problem. I've tried adding:

```
CharacterSet=1200
CharacterSet=65001
```

But the problem always remains the same. In what format does Excel save on Mac?
Anything I can try?